# Automatically build using the latest tag

Tags: java, jenkins

Is there a way of setting up a job, that builds using the latest tag from a SVN repository?

The project structure is as follows

```
Project
|
|\trunk
|\branches
|\tags
 |
 |\REL_1.0.1
 |\REL_1.0.2
 |\REL_1.0.3
 |\REL_1.1.0
 |\REL_1.1.1
```

[image: Miaow]

I would like to replace REL_1.1.1, such that it always uses the latest tag.

**EDIT**: This is using Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Have Hudson monitor a particular url. Say `repo/latesttag`. Suppose that latesttag has a file `tag.txt` with the tag name. The tag.txt gets updated through a `post-commit` hook whenever a new tag is added  ( through a new commit ). Now with every commit to tag.txt, ie whenever a new tag is created, a build gets triggered and use the tagname from the tag.txt to checkout / switch an existing checked out version of the previous latest tag and start a build from there.

Comment: But how would I open the file, read the latest tag, and use it as a variable to identify the complete url i.e. http://localhost:8080/repos/Project/tags/${latest_tag}. Can you give me a good reference to do this.